# if and else statement in laravel 4

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel, boolean, statements

I wanted my boolean to result in "true" or "false" instead of 1 and 0. So i tried using if and else statements to get results that I want to reflect in my User Interface. However, I still encountered some errors and I don't know where I made a mistake.

This is my code in the View folder

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('body')

<div class="well">
            <table class="table">


                <thead>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>lastname</th>
                    <th>firstname</th>
                    <th>middlename</th>
                    <th>hscard</th>
                    <th>tor</th>
                    <th>dismissal</th>
                    <th>goodmoral</th>
                    <th>birth certificate</th>
                    <th>form 137</th>
                    <th>grade evaluation</th>

                </thead>
                @foreach ($results as $result)

                <tr>

                    <td>{{$result->studentid}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->middlename}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->hscard}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->tor}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->dismissal }}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->goodmoral}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->bcrtfcate}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->form137}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->grade_evaluation}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>

        </div>
@stop
```

I tried adding this at if and else statement, and I still encountered some errors:

```
<td>{{$result->grade_evaluation}}
     @if($result==1)
     true
     @else
     false
</td>
```

Comment: You need to end the if statement with `@endif`

Comment: hello matt! I did not receive any errors anymore thanks however, all of my rows is labeled false, and the "1" won't echo true

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, could you be a bit more excplicit on that? You are outputting `$result->grade_evaluation` and then it seems you are comparing an object with an integer which will throw a notice and eventually evaluate to true and thus always output true.

Comment: @NattyGuurl That is because `$result` does not equal `1`, it is a model. If you use it on a property of the model then you may get different results.

Comment: @Thomas Actually my grade_evaluation is a boolean variable and when I reflect it on my User Interface it prints 1 and 0. What i wanted it to print is supposed to be true and false. In my DB its actually true and false.

Comment: @MattBurrow Oh i see, thank you matt! I'll try figuring it

Comment: Try that one: `{{ $result->grade_evaluation == 1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}`

Comment: **Clarification:** `$result` is actually an object. If you compare it to an Integer it will try to cast the object to an Integer which does not work (PHP will throw a notice). The comparision (if not you're not using strict comparison) will evaluate to true, though. You actually wanted to compare the `grade_evaluation` property (which might be an integer), but you compared with the whole object. I shortened the comparision with a ternary operator (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: You can btw drop the `== 1` completely. So everything that evaluates to true will output true. I somehow skipped when you wrote that the properties value is a boolean.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Thanks for the ternary operator guide, It's of great use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a Laravel issue, it is a PHP issue.

If the $result variable has a value, it will return the value. 
If it doesn't, it will return 0.

If you want to test if the $result variable has a value or not,
you better use the isset() function and try something like

```
@if(isset($result))
     true
@else
     false
@endif
```

The code above should work as you expect.